# Julia package add (zip master file from github)

Tags: package, installation, julia

I am trying to install/add manually the *.jl-master.zip files, I am doing this because I have a computer without access to internet  but I don't know how to do the offline installation.

The version of Julia is 1.3.0 and the O.S. Windows 10

I had tried this,

[Instruction I followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000798/how-to-install-a-julia-package-offline-in-julia-1-0)

but for me It does not work.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: "It does not work" is not a sufficient description of you problem.

Answer (score 3):

Installing Julia packages offline is very difficult due to the fact how binary dependencies work.

You have basically two options:

- buying JuliaTeam/JuliaPro from Julia Computing (maybe someone who is using it will ever see that thread and could share their experience?)
- hacking

Regarding the second option the best bet is to install all required packages on a different machine having and copy the `.julia` folder to your offline machine (or, depending on your configuration folder referenced by the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` system environment variable).

However, in most cases you will need to rebuild several packages. The problem is that Julia packages have several binary dependencies that come from different sources. This problem has been noted by the Julia community and is being addressed by the [Julia Artifacts](https://julialang.org/blog/2019/11/artifacts) mechanism.

Today the most common step is to manually edit `deps/build.jl` file in each Julia package that is downloading binary resources in its build process and make the build code to point to files in your local repository. Once done you can rebuild the package offline by running `using Pkg;Pkg.build("PackageName")`.

Comment: The third option would be to use a container, which should be straight forward.

Comment: @fredrikerke, yes, and yet another option an image of a virtual machine. However, neither dockerization nor virtualization are not Julia specific - those options are always there for any computing technology. What I really miss is some good tool to pack Julia packages for offline use. There are some attempt to do it on Github but seem to be very preliminary